# How to structure friendship data with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm novice with firebase and I try to structure my data to store friendship between users of my app.

My data are structured like this :

```
    { users: {
        user_1: {
          name: John
        },
        user_2: {
          name: Jack
        },
       user_3: { 
          name: Georges
       },
   }, 
   { friendships : {
      user_1 : {
        user_2: {
            name: Jack
          },
        user_3: {
            name: Georges
      },
      user_3: {
        user_1: {
            name: John
        },
         user_2: {
            name: Jack
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if my data structure is OK, but I wonder what is the best way to update a name in the friendships if a user changes his name, how can I easily update the reference in the friendships (brows each node ?) ?

Thank you if someone can help me to understand the right way to do that.

A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your structure is almost good, but I would change the friendships node to this:

```
    { users: {
        user_1: {
          name: John
        },
        user_2: {
          name: Jack
        },
       user_3: { 
          name: Georges
       },
   }, 
   { friendships : {
      user_1 : {
        user_2: true,
        user_3: true,
      user_3: {
        user_1: true,
        user_2: true
    }
}
```

This is similar to what Dravidian showed, but depending on how many friends you have, it might be a better idea to not store the users friendslist under the users account details node because if you had 1000+ friends you would have to download 1000 children even if you just wanted to get a single value like his name.

Comment: How would you retreive friend data because I am guessing user node will have .read and .write restricted to the actual user.

Answer (score 6):

The database structure that you are following is a bit messy and might prove a bit hard to navigate through it,  Might i suggest :-

```
  Users{
    userID_1 : {
      username : “Shelly Morgan”  ,     
      useremail : “sehlly1@yahoo.co.in”
       friends :{
        userID_2 : true,
        userID_3 : true,
        userID_4 : true,
                 } 
           },
    userID_2 : {
     username : “Mikael”  ,     
     useremail : “mike1232@gmail.com”
       friends :{
        userID_1 : true,
        userID_4 : true,
                 } 
           },
    userID_3 : {
     username : “Lenoard Narish”  ,     
     useremail : “leo_nar12@gmail.com”
      friends :{
        userID_1 : true,
        userID_2 : true,
        userID_4 : true,
                 } 
           },
    userID_4 : {
     username : “Rob Stark”  ,     
     useremail : “robStar781@gmail.com”
      friends :{
         userID_1 : true
                 } 
           }

}
```

In this manner you only store the `userID` of friends in that users database, and all you have to do is change the values in only `friends_uid` node.To retrieve the `friends`  database:-

1.)  just hit the `friends` node of that `User`

2.)  listen for every friends `uid`,

3.)  and hit the database with the desired `uid` to retrieve database of respective `friend`

Read the documentation in here for retrieving the data : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Comment: I read the firebase documentation and it recommends to avoid nested data : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data, what do you think about that ?

Comment: Yes if you are going to use it for Real-Time database or so... like for chat , Sending Notification etc. but for storing the static values, its fine.Flatten DataStructures are needed when you need to have a close link to child from parent root like in `Search Engines` OR if your datastructure requires `Weighting`. I think your structure would work fine with this

Comment: OK, I now understand better, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store `name` in the `friendships` structure, only the usernames. So `friendships` should look more like this:

```
{
    friendships: {
        user_1: [
            user_2,
            user_3
        ],
        user_2: [
            user_1
        ]
    }
}
```

This way if you update `name`, you only have update it in one place (`users`). You can cross-reference the username from `friendships` with the username in `users` to find `name`.

Also in case you use [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) for friendships, the structure will change a little, but the same principle applies:

```
{
    friendships: {
        user_1: {
            -KPE008BeSzNR5D3W7t3: user_2,
            -KPE0nF4AW7Lj66xTLUu: user_3
        },
        ...
    }
}
```