# Build the data structure with relationship via Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am new in noSQL and Firebase. But I want to build the structure of my database via Firebase.

I have users and a list of users lots. Structure with relationship.
So I did what's [in the example:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

```
 String key = mDatabase.child("lots").push().getKey();
    //create new lot
    Lot lot = new Lot(fbUser.getUid(), fbUser.getEmail(),  mMessage.getText().toString());
    //turn to map
    Map<String, Object> lotValues = lot.toMap();
    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/lots/" + key, lotValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-lots/" + fbUser.getUid() + "/" + key, lotValues);
    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

But in the result I had this data to duplicate:

[image: this]

May be it's better to get this [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38960217/6352712). I tried to find an example how to build one, because I do not want to to reinvent a wheel, but my efforts are futile so far.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to have a pointer to another node in the database? If so that's not possible, don't be surprised, Firebase has TONS of missing important features such as collection filtering, one-to-one upstream messages, and this.

Comment: @AbAppletic so, as example, if i want to get data such as "best-user-lot" in one request, i must to create a separete branch for data filling, like this:  /best_user_lots/user_id/lots_id ?

Comment: Yes. You do. It's very unfortunate that Firebase doesn't provide a way to do it without excess data, but it has to be done the way you're currently doing it.

Comment: @AbAppletic Oh thanks a lot! I am trying second day to to understand structure in firebas, and now I have  finished, may be))

Comment: Good luck then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Pointers`, which Firebase, believe it or not, **DOES NOT** have.

For example, if you want to have 3 lists of data:

1. My Posts
2. Recent Posts

Then you'll have to do it like this:

```
databaseRoot:{
  Posts:{
     {UNQ_KEY}:
      {
        title: "x",
        description: "y",
        authorUserID: {USERID1}
      }
   }

  Users:{
    {USERID1}
      Posts:{
        {UNQ_KEY_2}: {
         title: "x",
         description: "y"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

When `UNQ_KEY`  is created, you also create `UNQ_KEY_2` under the user's userID.

To display "**My Posts**", you get the list under `{USERID1}`. To get "**Recent Posts**", you have to go to the `Posts` node.